# SSRS Report Query Type Text - Must declare parameter error

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a SSRS Report. I am getting error while coping the `Store procedure` sql code to Query type `Text`. **(SP code to Query type Text)**

I searched on google and stackoverflow but could not find the proper fixing solution so I am posting here.

**Getting Below Error:**

[image: Error is something like this]

See I know, that this error is of scalar variable. Ignore the last message `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

So the question, when we use query type text, how should I declare the variable.  Like in store procedure it will automatically adds to Parameters.

Also, query type text does not support set variable then what should I do?

```
Sample query

SELECT @ToDate = CAST(MAX(@ToDate) AS DATETIME) + ' 23:59:59.000'                       
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  EndDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @ToDate
```

Please help me, guide me or suggest me the best solution to overcome this issue.

**Note:** I don't want to use `Query Type Store Procedure`. I just want to use `Query Type Text Only`

Comment: Are you able to post the query?

Comment: Can you post you Query in dataSet ?

Comment: Down vote with comment would be better!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found the issue, So when you write your SQL query in Report Designer **(*Query Type Text)***,

**1** *Variable must be declare OR Set like below,*

```
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME; -- ended with semicolon ";"
SET @ToDate = CAST(MAX(@ToDate) AS DATETIME) + ' 23:59:59.000'; -- ended with semicolon ";"
```

**2** *Do not have multiple selected value from same table. It will throw error.*

***For example:***

`Select BillNumber,Name,BillNumber From XYZ -- BillNumber should not be twice`

Answer (score 1):

> Sample query
>
> SELECT @ToDate = CAST(MAX(@ToDate) AS DATETIME) + ' 23:59:59.000'
>   SELECT * FROM   TableName WHERE  EndDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @ToDate

```
 declare @ToDate datetime
  --set @ToDate='2015-10-09' this is for example
  SELECT @ToDate = CAST(MAX(@ToDate) AS DATETIME) + ' 23:59:59.000'
  ---select @ToDate
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE EndDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @ToDate
```

Comment: first thing, no need to use multiple select query in Query type text, second I will pass  @ToDate as parameter so no need to set it in query part. It will not solve my issue.

Comment: please declare a variable  declare @ToDate datetime in your query

Answer (score 0):

You should try the query in SSMS first, get it working there before pasting into an SSRS report.

To declare the variables inside an RDL file the syntax is:

`<QueryParameter Name="@ToDate">
    <Value>=Parameters!ToDate.Value</Value>
 </QueryParameter>
 <Query>
        <DataSourceName>xxxyourdatasourcexxx</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT X,Y,Z FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME WHERE X = @ToDate</CommandText>
 </Query>`

Comment: I have already checked the output in SSMS first and it's all working fine.

Comment: I have checked in view code also, it's all fine now I am going to delete the dataset and will make it again. thanks for your kind help.